# JavaScript - Text manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do some manipulation with text inputted on a form. I can get the individual parts to work but putting it all together is failing, I am guessing its something simple but I can't spot it. If someone could cast an eye and point out any mistakes I would be most happy. Thanks

My Code:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#open').click(function() {

        //  Data for dashboards

        var fixedData1 = 'http://10.0.0.0:0000/dashboard/db/dashboard-test?var-vip1=',
            userEntry1 =  $('#one').val(),
            fixedData2 = '&var-vip2=',
            fixedData3 = '&var-nsPathSplice=',
            fixedData4 = '&var-OpsUrl=',
            check = userEntry1.replace('.dfw.', '.dal.')

        // Convert VIP into nsPathS

        var nsPathSplice = "/" + userEntry1.split(".").slice(1, 4).reverse().join("/") + "/BOM*";
        if (check == userEntry1) {
            check = userEntry1.replace('.dal.', '.dfw.')
        }

        // Convert nsPath into Ops URL

        function intercolateIntoPath(nsPathSplice) {
        var InputPieces = nsPathSplice.split('/');
        var outputPieces = [
        'https://ops.prod.com', InputPieces[0], 'assemblies', InputPieces[1],
        'operations/environments', InputPieces[2]
        ];
        return outputPieces.join('/');
        }

        // Join everything and create new URL String

        var url = fixedData1 + userEntry1 + fixedData2 + check + fixedData3 + nsPathSplice + fixedData4 + outputPieces
        console.log(url)
        var newWindow = window.open(url);
    })
});
```

Where userEntry1 example:

app-search.prod-a.search.laris.dal.prod.com-HTTP_80tcp-0000000000-lb

**Covert to nsPath (Works)**

Input = app-search.prod-a.search.laris.dal.prod.com-HTTP_80tcp-0000000000-lb

Output = /laris/search/prod-a/BOM*

**Convert nsPath to Ops URL (Not Working)**

Input = /laris/search/prod-a/BOM*

Output Should =  https://ops.prod.com/laris/assemblies/search/operations/environments/prod-a

**Join it all together**

var url = fixedData1 + userEntry1 + fixedData2 + check + fixedData3 + nsPathSplice + fixedData4 + outputPieces
    console.log(url)
    var newWindow = window.open(url);

Comment: There are a few missing semicolons. Fix that and then check.

Comment: I don't see where, I've passed it through a validater to check if it was anything like that and as far as I can tell the code in syntactically correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I was calling 'outputPieces' instead of 'intercolateIntoPath'

```
var url = fixedData1 + userEntry1 + fixedData2 + check + fixedData3 + nsPathSplice + fixedData4 + outputPieces console.log(url)

var url = fixedData1 + userEntry1 + fixedData2 + check + fixedData3 + nsPathSplice + fixedData4 + intercolateIntoPath console.log(url)
```